# CodeValue (Lookup) Table into multiple Entities

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

I am beginning work to re-write a software that would deal with a pre-existing SQL 2005 database (that was originally created in SQL 6.5, then migrated to SQL 2005).

One of the tables is a "lookup table" (contains code-values for multiple picklists (statuses, Qualifiers, Types of this, types of that, etc).  In all, 16 categories.

dbo.ReferenceItem
   ReferenceItem_ID int (PK)
   ReferenceTable_ID int (items for a picklist have the same ID, 16 different values - for the 16 picklists)
   Description varchar(30) --> This is the display value for the picklist

How would I go about making separate entities in EF 5.0 ?

I would like to have an EF entity for each category (ReferenceTable_ID) within the ReferenceItem table.

I was looking into Table-per-Hierarchy Inheritance, but hit a wall in the Table Mapping.

**Could anyone gently guide me as to how this could be accomplished within EF 5 ?   If possible, I don't want to modify the database.**

Thank you in advence.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this ?